# what is the use of the sort -d option I'm confused in it?

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

I want to know the use of the sort -d command in Unix.

It will sort based on the dictionary order but when I checked with the input I didn't get how it is working.

```
   The input is:
   | hi 
   |hi
   |   hello
   |hello
   |  hello

    output:
    |hello
    |  hello
    |   hello
    |hi
    | hi
```

Can somebody explain me clearly with and example.
Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

All it's doing is sorting by dictionary order and it assumes because there are spaces/tabs before certain ones that they go after the original with no padding.

Not sure what the question really is, but hope that helps.

Comment: dictionary order in the sense what does it means? can you explain with example?

Comment: if a doc had the text "apples\ pears\ bananas". It would order it: "apples\ bananas\ pears".

Answer (score 0):

dictionary order in the sense, that it is ignoring all not alphanumeric characters. simple example is a file list with some files prefixed by `./`. If you use a non POSIX LANG (e.g. I am using en_US.UTF-8) sort doesn't work correctly in the sense that it seems to sor always as if -d is specified. SO it might well be, that you do not see a difference between using -d and omitting it on your system

If you set the LANG environment to 'C'  (LC_ALL shoudl work as well) it works as expected.

order in file:

```
~ » echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
~ » cat to_sort.txt
b
./a
./c
```

then sort -d

```
~ » sort -d to_sort.txt
./a
b
./c
```

same as without -d

```
~ » sort to_sort.txt
./a
b
./c
```

with a POSIX lang the default is as expected:

```
~ » LANG=C sort to_sort.txt
./a
./c
b
~ »
```

and -d works as well:

```
~ » LANG=C sort -d to_sort.txt
./a
b
./c
```